# Flutter LBS to KG app not registrating "Convert" submit

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm doing my first Flutter app where I want to take LBS as input and show it as KG.

I've created two double variables, one for **_lbs** and one for the **_kg** value.

I have a method that converts lbs input to kg output.

However when I press the Convert button nothing is happening in my app.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'LBS to KG converter';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form Widget
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class. This class will hold the data related to
// the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  double _lbs;
  double _kg;

  void _convert(){
    setState(() {
      _kg = _lbs * 0.45359237;
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Form(

      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          /*- LBS ---------------- */
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 2.0, left: 10.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "LBS:",
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  )
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 2.0, left: 10.0),
                  child: new TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '$_lbs'
                  ),)

                ),
              )
            ],
          ),



          /*- KG ----------------- */
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 2.0, left: 10.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      "KG:",
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 2.0, left: 10.0),
                    child: new TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: '$_kg'
                    ),)

                ),
              )
            ],
          ),

          /*- Convert ---------------- */
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 15.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _convert,
                    child: new Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 60.0,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF18D191),
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                        child: new Text("Convert",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1) Any suggestions on what I am missing in my app?

2) Is "hintText" the best method of showing the value? Is there not any "TextField.value" ?

Comment: `_lbs` is null everytime. You never change it's value - that's what you missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final lbsController = TextEditingController();
final kgController = TextEditingController();

void _convert(){
_lbs = lbsController.text; // just add checking for digital input there
  setState(() {
    _kg = _lbs * 0.45359237;
  });
}
```

And inside `build`

```
lbsController.text = _lbs;
kgController.text = _kg;
...
child: new TextField(controller: lbsController, ...
```

Comment: to complete this answer, when you cast (lbsController.text) into your value, the text is STRING, you'll get an error, then you have to parse it as Int or Double by doing this:
 _lbs = double.parse(lbsController.text)  - or -  _lbs = int.parse(lbsController.text). In this case, you have to parse it as DOUBLE